# Expected value with indicator random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I don't understand the solution for problem 7a at http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/geir/teaching/m362k/weeklyhw9solns.pdf. Reproduced below for reference:

> Suppose that A and B each randomly, and independently,
>   choose 3 of 10 objects. Find the expected number of objects chosen by both A and B.
>
> solution: Let $X$ be the number of objects chosen by both A and B. For $1 \le i \le
> 10$, let $$
> \begin{align}
> X_i = \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } \text{object i is chosen by A and B} \\
> 0 &\mbox{otherwise } \end{cases} 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Then $X = X_1 + ... + X_{10}$. We find $$
> E[X_i] = 0\cdot P(X_i = 0) + 1\cdot P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = 1) = 9/100.
> $$
>   By the linearity of expectation, $$E[X] = 10\cdot E[X_i] = 0.9$$

I don't understand how they reduced $E[X_i]$ (don't they need $P(X_i = 2, 3, ..., 10)$ terms?) and how $9/100$ was computed.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand how they reduced $E[X_i]$ (don't they need $P(X_i = 2, 3, ..., 10)$ terms?)

By definition, the only two values taken by $X_i$ are $0$ and $1$. I think you may be confusing $X_i$ with $i$. You can think of $i$ as being fixed for the duration of the sentence beginning "We find $E[X_i] =$ ..."

> and how $9/100$ was computed.

We want the probability that A chose object $i$ *and* B chose object $i$. These two events are independent by assumption. What does that independence tell us?

Comment: Ah I see, so $E[X_i]$ is basically $E[\text{object i is chosen by A and B}]$.

Comment: As for the $9/100$, i still don't understand

Comment: @FrankEpps The calculation of $E[X_i]=9/100$ comes from the basic definition of expected value: $E[X_i] = \sum_k k \cdot P(X_i=k)$, except that in this case, $k$ can only be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: No I understand that part now. But I don't understand the calculation part of it: $P(\text{object i is chosen by A and B})$, how to find that probability

Comment: @FrankEpps Since $A$ and $B$ make choices independently, we have $P(\text{object }i\text{ is chosen by }A\text{ and }B) = P(\text{chosen by }A) \cdot P(\text{chosen by }B) = (3/10)^2$

Comment: In case anyone was still wondering why P(object i is chosen by A) is 3/10:
$$
$$  
If A chooses 3 out of 10, the sample space is the set of all 3-sets chosen from 10:
$$ 
{10 \choose 3}
$$
And the number of these sets that will contain the 'i' of interest is [first pick 'i' and then out of the remaining 9 you can choose any two]  
: 
$$
1 { 9 \choose 2 }
$$
So the final probability is:
$$
\frac{9 \choose 2}{10 \choose 3} = 3/10
$$